# Сериализация данных в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, сериализация

Я только начинаю изучать django. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сериализовать данные (необходимо заменить id значениями LoanTypeParticipation и Name).
Сейчас получаю следующий результат:

```
0: {Id_Incidents: 120, Id_Group: 13, Type_Participation: "p", Id_People: 2, Competencies: "есть"}
```

Serialize.py

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import AkpGroup, AkpPeople


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Name = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AkpGroup
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views.py

```
def load_table(request):
    error = ''
    id_incidents = request.session.get('Id_Incidents', 'ничего не передано')

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user:
            try:
                persons = AkpGroup.objects.filter(Id_Incidents=120)  # запрос в базу данных

            except AkpGroup.objects.DoesNotExist:
                persons = None

            serializer = GroupSerializer(persons, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Models.py

```
class AkpPeople(models.Model):
    Id_People = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Идентификатор участника группы АКП')
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Ф.И.О.')
    Post = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Должность:')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.Name
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.Name, self.Post)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'akp_people'
        verbose_name = 'Участник группы АКП'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Участники групп АКП'


class AkpGroup(models.Model):
Id_Group = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Идентификатор участника группы АКП')
Id_Incidents = models.ForeignKey('AkpIncidents', models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Идентификатор инцидента')
# stage 3 fields
Id_People = models.ForeignKey('AkpPeople', models.DO_NOTHING,
                              related_name='AkpGroups', verbose_name='Ф.И.О. участника')
Competencies = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Компетенции')

LoanTypeParticipation = (
    ('d', 'Руководитель группы'),
    ('p', 'Член группы')
)
Type_Participation = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LoanTypeParticipation,
                                      verbose_name='Тип участия')
# Вспомогательные
Change_Time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Время изменения')
Change_User = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Пользователь, внесший изменения')
Del_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Дата удаления')
Del_User = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Пользователь, удаливший данные')

Is_Delete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Удален')
Is_Posted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Опублековано')

objects = models.Manager()

def display_id_people(self):
    """
    Creates a string for the Genre. This is required to display genre in Admin.
    """
    return ', '.join([Id_People.Name for Id_People in self.Id_People.all()[:10]])
display_id_people.short_description = 'AkpGroup'

def __str__(self):
    return self.Competencies

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Akp_Group'
    verbose_name = 'Группа АКП'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Группы АКП'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения задачи требовалось передать сериализованные данные модели AkpPeople по внешнему ключу модели AkpGroup.

Для решения использовал:

1. Видеоурок: https://youtu.be/sxdPf3z6Uw8
2. Пример реализации: https://github.com/TonikX/ITMO_ICT_WebDevelopment_Examples/tree/example-serializers/example_2310

**Решение:**

***Serialize.py***

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers


class PeopleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AkpPeople
        fields = ['Name', 'Post']


class FilialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AkpFilial
        fields = ['Name_Filial']


class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AkpDepartment
        fields = ['Name_Department']
    

class GroupNestedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # делаем наследование
    Id_People = PeopleSerializer()
    # уточняем поле
    Type_Participation = serializers.CharField(source="get_Type_Participation_display", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AkpGroup
        fields = ['Id_Incidents', 'Id_Group', 'Type_Participation', 'Id_People', 'Competencies']

class IncidentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupNestedSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    filial = FilialSerializer(source='Id_Filial')
    department = DepartmentSerializer(source='Id_Department')

    class Meta:
        model = AkpIncidents
        fields = ['Id_Incidents', 'Date', 'filial', 'department', 'Short_Description', 'groups']
```

***Views.py***

```
def load_table(request):
    error = ''
    id_incidents = request.session.get('Id_Incidents', 'ничего не передано')
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user:
            try:
                incidents = AkpIncidents.objects.get(Id_Incidents=id_incidents)  # запрос в базу данных

            except AkpIncidents.objects.DoesNotExist:
               
                incidents = None
           
            serializer = IncidentsSerializer(incidents, many=True)
            
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=403)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=405)
```

***Urls.py***

```
app_name = "main"

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.start, name="start"),
        path('incident', views.incident, name="incident"),
        path('victim', views.victim, name="victim"),
        path('group', views.Groups.as_view(), name='group'),
        path('CheckResult', views.CheckResult.as_view(), name='CheckResult'),
        path('AdditionalDetail', views.additional_detail, name='AdditionalDetail'),
        path('events', views.events, name='events'),
        path('monitoring', views.monitoring, name='monitoring'),
    
        path(
            'url_to_django/delete_person/<int:Id_Group>',
            views.delete_person,
            name='delete_person'),
        path(
            'url_to_django/add_person/',
            views.add_person,
            name='add_person'),
        path(
            'url_to_django/load_table/',
            load_table,
            name='load_table')
```

**Дополнение:**

***Views.py***

Для решения задачи было бы гораздо лучше расположить смежные функции внутри одного класса. Я только начал изучать Django, и пока не понял как обратиться непосредственно к конкретной функции, находящейся внутри класса.

```
class GroupListRelatedAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = AkpIncidents.objects.filter(Id_Incidents=id_incidents)
    serializer_class = IncidentsSerializer

    def load_table(request):
    *********
    def delete_person(request, Id_Group):
    *********
    def add_person(request):
    *********
```

***Urls.py***

```
app_name = "main"

    urlpatterns = [
                
        path(
            'url_to_django/load_table/',
            GroupListRelatedAPIView.as_view(),
            name='load_table')
```